# Is the hydrogen peroxide therapy harmful?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, natural-remedies

I'm receiving advertising (from my friends) about hydrogen peroxide therapy (oxygenated water, I think). They affirm that this treatment is

> a low-cost therapy based on a natural 
>   oxygenating substance that is easy and
>   painless to use at home -- and which
>   is scientifically proven to prevent
>   and cure virtually all diseases
>   without adverse effects.

I'm worried about my friends that are trying to convince me and they probably are drinking it. What are the dangers or risks of doing this?

**Update**:

I did a little research, the product is called Oxytam that is made

> distilling hydrogen peroxide for
>   propulsion purposes, leaving a residue
>   that is pure bi-distilled water and
>   tri-distilled hydrogen peroxide.

The email has a reference to a [website](http://www.oneminutecureforalldiseases.com) in order to "learn more" about this treatment. Although the manufacturer offers two languages to choose from in the start page, the product (Oxytam) page ( http://www.tecaeromex.com/esp/ph-cura.htm ) is offered only in spanish; apparently because they distribute only locally.

Comment: "Oxygenated water" means the same as [aerated water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_aeration) - water with oxygen dissolved in it. It is what fish need to "breathe". Hydrogen Peroxide is H2O2, which isn't water - it happens to have molecules made of similar elements, but it is very  different.

Comment: Two friends go to a bar.  One says, "I'll have a glass of H2O."  The second says, "I'll have a glass of H2O, too."  The second one dies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Concentrated Hydrogen peroxide solutions ([MSDS from Merck for a 30% solution](http://www.emdchemicals.com/hydrogen-peroxide-solution/EMD_CHEM-HX0640/p_uuid?attachments=MSDS)) are strongly oxidizing and corrosive. Those should only be handled with proper safety procedures and euqipment (especially safety glasses).

The Emergency overview from the MSDS states:

> DANGER! OXIDIZER. CONTACT WITH OTHER
>   MATERIAL MAY CAUSE FIRE. CAUSES
>   RESPIRATORY TRACT, EYE AND SKIN BURNS.
>   HARMFUL IF INHALED OR SWALLOWED. MAY
>   BE HARMFUL IF ABSORBED THROUGH SKIN.
>   CONTAINS MATERIAL WHICH MAY CAUSE
>   DAMAGE TO THE FOLLOWING ORGANS: MUCOUS
>   MEMBRANES, RESPIRATORY TRACT, SKIN,
>   EYE, LENS OR CORNEA, NOSE, SINUSES.

Lower concentrated solutions (around 3-8% H2O2) [are used to bleach hair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide), that should give you an idea that this is a pretty reactive chemical.

The Hong Kong Center for Food safety [says the following about ingesting highly diluted solutions of hydrogen peroxide](http://www.cfs.gov.hk/english/programme/programme_rafs/programme_rafs_fa_02_02.html)

> Oral ingestion of 3% hydrogen peroxide
>   solutions (household strength)
>   generally does not result in severe
>   toxicity but may result in vomiting,
>   mild irritation to mucosa and burns in
>   the mouth, throat, oesophagus and
>   stomach. Ingestion of higher
>   concentration, e.g. >10%, can result
>   in more dangerous sequelae such as
>   burns to mucus membranes and gut
>   mucosa.

I would guess that the therapy you asked about uses far lower concentrations of H2O2 than 3 percent, because the higher concentrations are likely to cause some unwanted effects. Whether the ingestion is really dangerous depends strongly on the concentration of the hydrogen peroxide solution. I personally wouldn't ingest it in any case, but if it a very highly diluted solution it probably doesn't do much of anything.

I would be worried about handling higher concentrated H2O2 solutions, e.g. if they add concentrated H2O2 to the water themselves, they have to be careful when handling it.

Comment: The bottle of hydrogen peroxide I have says you can actually use it as mouthwash but do NOT swallow as it can be harmful. So definitely a topical antiseptic.

Comment: This is not a proof; sometimes things can be counter-intuitive. For instance , Ascorbic acid is apparently an anti-oxidant? Who would have thought. What do you say to the underoxygenation theory? http://educate-yourself.org/cancer/benefitsofhydrogenperozide17jul03.shtml 90% alcohol is also unpleasant to drink and leads to health issues, but 5% beer or 12% wine is liked by many.

Comment: Low-concentration H2O2 is sold and widely used as a topical antiseptic (minor wounds, bruises) at least in my part of the world. Of course very small doses and external only for this use case.