# Can Hydrogen Peroxide administered via ear drops reduce the duration of the common cold?

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies

I was looking for information about common colds and this URL came up on page 1 via Google search:

[Vitamin D and Other Simple, Inexpensive Tricks to Cure a Cold](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2010/11/22/the-common-cold-simple-strategies-for-prevention-and-treatment.aspx) (on mercola.com)

There's a section in it titled **Hydrogen Peroxide: A Simple Trick to Beat a Cold**

> I don't advise over-the-counter medications, but one simple treatment you can try that is surprisingly effective against upper respiratory infections is hydrogen peroxide. Many patients at my Natural Health Center have had remarkable results in curing colds and flu within 12 to 14 hours when administering a few drops of 3 percent hydrogen peroxide (H2O2) into each ear. You will hear some bubbling, which is completely normal, and possibly feel a slight stinging sensation. Wait until the bubbling and stinging subside (usually 5 to 10 minutes), then drain onto a tissue and repeat with the other ear. A bottle of hydrogen peroxide in 3 percent solution is available at any drug store for a couple of dollars or less. It is simply amazing how many people respond to this simple, inexpensive treatment.

It details a process to administer 3% Hydrogen Peroxide that reduces the cold to a 12-14 hour duration.

Is this claim valid?  It seems a bit dangerous to drop (even highly diluted) Hydrogen Peroxide into one's ear?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a notable claim. It's just a claim on a single site. The article itself has a number of laughable claims. The rest of the site is cringeworthy.

Comment: [More](http://wellnessmama.com/1499/natural-remedies-for-illness/) [evidence](http://www.green-talk.com/hydrogen-peroxide-ears-bye-to-colds-a-remedy-that-works/) that this is a [notable](http://www.thesuntimes.com/article/20121130/News/121139989) [claim](http://www.healingdaily.com/exercise/hydrogen-peroxide-in-ears.htm).  Hydrogen Peroxide [has appeared on Skeptics before](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/is-the-hydrogen-peroxide-therapy-harmful) in a claim that it can "prevent and cure virtually all diseases".

Comment: @Tim - " It seems a bit dangerous to drop" - is definitely NOT relevant to the claim; and probably false assumption: that's a **popular** "natural" method of treating ear inflammation. if it was dangerous it would be a lot less popular (then again, so are Q-tips, so maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: @DVK There are a great many dangerous things that are very popular, such as gambling, smoking cigarettes and drunk driving.

Comment: @Superbest - those are popular due to increasing serotonin levels. I don't think putting H.P. in your ear results in a rush or is addictive :)

Comment: @DVK Not every dangerous habit is purely a consequence of high serotonin. Homeopathic medicine (granted, not very dangerous) and fad dieting (you could argue that all eating disorders are just "increasing serotonin levels" but I don't think you'd be right), for example. Anyway, the point is, people aren't rational and sometimes do dangerous things anyway.

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide (at 10 volumes strength) in the ear is not dangerous, it is used by mainstream professionals to loosen blockages caused by buildup of ear wax. I suspect that the effervescence of released oxygen has a mechanical loosening effect.

Comment: I'd say that any benefits seen in his "Natural Health Center" are purely from placebo effect since there is not (normally) any pathway from the outer ear to the rest of the body, and no reason to think that a localized effect in the ear can have a healing effect on the rest of the body.